# Compare successive rows Alteryx

Tags: alteryx

I have a spreadsheet with order item in column A, order quantity in column B, order start date in column C, and order finish date in column D. What I would like to do is treat orders on consecutive start dates for the same item as one single order. So until there is at least one days break between order start dates for an order item, treat it as one single order. Then I need to count the orders, sum the order quantities and calculate the average gap in days between orders (gap between order finish date and the next order start date). So if an order item was ordered on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th of March, and then again on the 10th and 11th of March, and then again on the 20th March (with all orders having the same start and finish date), there would be 2 gaps, which the average gap being 7.5 days ((6+9)/2). So the input and output will look like this;

[image]

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Discussion...

1. The fields I've defined are `OrderItem`, `OrderQty`, `OrderStartDate`, and `OrderEndDate`, plugging in values identical to those you provided.
2. The Select tool just forces `OrderQty` to `Int32`
3. MultiRow Formula, creates new `Int32` variable `Gap` using this expression:

   `IIF(IsNull([Row-1:OrderStartDate]), 1, DateTimeDiff([OrderStartDate], [Row-1:OrderStartDate],"Days"))`
4. First Summary tool:

- `Group By` `OrderItem` ...
- `Group By` `Gap` ...
- `Sum` `OrderQty` to new output field `OrdersPerGap`

5. a. Top avenue Summary tool:

- `Group By` `OrderItem` ...
- `Sum` `OrdersPerGroup` to output field name `OrderQty` ...
- `Count` `OrderItem` to output field name `NumOrders`

5. b. Bottom avenue, simple filter as shown `Gap > 1` and then another summary:

- `Group By` `OrderItem` ...
- `Avg` `Gap` to new output field `AvgGap`

6. `Join` the two strains back together on `OrderItem` and exclude `Right_OrderItem` from the output (uncheck its checkbox).

In Alteryx, this provides the output requested.  There may be other ways but this is straight-forward without too much going on any step.